# tmux status line with blank line on top?

Tags: terminal, tmux

I have a nice tmux status line, but I don't like how the bash/commands run flush along it. That is, if the screen is full, I'm typing things right above the status line.

I'd like a one line break above it, so that what I'm typing never "touches" the status line; is there any way to do this?

Example:

Let's say I have a very small terminal window that is two lines long

```
bash>$ (cursor)
1: bash*  2: bash-  3: vim-
```

How would I get a blank line to separate the status bar from the prompt, like:

```
bash>$ (cursor)

1: bash*  2: bash-  3: vim-
```

Comment: Could you provide a screen shot?

Comment: @Sardathrion I added a visual indication of what I am talking about, does that help? :)

Comment: [Powerline](https://github.com/Lokaltog/powerline) has some tmux bindings that you might find helpful.

Comment: `select-layout` should help, I think

Comment: Not a direct answer, but changing the background color of the status bar provides a good amount of visual distinction between the command line and the status bar.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind typing directly above the pane border (which you have to do anyway for any panel that doesn't touch the status line), you can force `tmux` to use a smaller window:

```
set force-height <single_window_height - 1>
```

However this only is a per-window setting and acts as maximum height limit hence it won't do what you want when you change your containing terminal dimesions.

Answer (score 1):

From https://github.com/tmux/tmux/issues/1886#issuecomment-525382148

```bsh
  set -Fg 'status-format[1]' '#{status-format[0]}'
  set -g 'status-format[0]' ''
  set -g status 2
```

This takes advantage of the multi-status bar support in tmux >= 2.9. It creates two status bars making the second your actual status bar and the first one a blank one to emulate white space